# Webscrapping with bs4: Type Error - 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, request, typeerror, nonetype

I am trying to extract "video" from the url and print how many there are in the console.

But I get this Error:

`TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`

Here is my code:

````
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

Web_url = "https://watch.plex.tv/show/hannibal/season/1/episode/9"
r = requests.get(Web_url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

video_tags = soup.find_all("video")
print("Total", len(video_tags), "videos found")

if len(video_tags) !=0:
    for video_tag in video_tags:
        video_url = video_tag.find("a")['href']
        print(video_url)```
````

Comment: At first,you have to specify what data do you wanna scrape?

Comment: Is "video" is class name or attr. Thus way can't grab anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably getting the error on the `video_url = video_tag.find("a")['href']` line, since I cannot see any other place where you're indexing, which is what can [cause this error](https://itsmycode.com/python-typeerror-nonetype-object-is-not-subscriptable/#:%7E:text=Conclusion-,The%20TypeError%3A%20%27%20NoneType%27%20object%20is%20not%20subscriptable%20error%20is,lists%2C%20dictionaries%2C%20and%20tuples.). So, the error would happen because `video_tag.find("a")` returns `None`. You should wrap it for some error handling like:

```
for video_tag in video_tags:
    video_hl = video_tag.find("a")
    if video_hl is None:
        print("No hyperlinks found inside the video tag", video_tag.attrs)
        continue
    video_url = video_hl['href']
    print(video_url)
```

(Printing the `video_tag.attrs` can help you `find` or `select` that `video` element for further inspection.)

[Actually, I can't get to that line when I run your code because I get *Total 0 videos found* so the for-loop never runs; but when I open and inspect the plex link you're using, the only `video` tag I can find is the "Watch Now" button (which does not get scraped when I run your code, for some reason), and that does not have any `a` tags in it - nor do any of the several other videos I inspected on the plex site.]

If you're trying to get the video source link rather that hyperlinks that [will show up when a browser doesn't support HTML video](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#usage_notes), you can get the `src` attribute with `video_src = video_tag.get('src')`